# Cannot toggle checkboxes and switch control in system settings

Tags: settings

I encountered recently `\dev\mapper\elementary--vg--root` error because I encountered BSOD in my host machine. I fixed the issue through `fsck /f`.

When I boot up again my VM, the startup wizard where this displays after the installation, popups again. I tried to turn off some settings through the wizard and also through system settings but the setting always reverted.

I added a gif image showing the issue.

[image: switch-settings]

Answer (score 0):

Did you boot in recovery mode?
It looks like your root volume was likely mounted *read-only*.
Can you remount it read/write with the following command?

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

For the error `IO charset iso8859-1 not found`, try booting into recovery mode and running `depmod` as [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1186125/1117671) mentions.

Comment: After trying the command, it says "IO charset iso8859-1 not found. You are in emergency mode" after reboot

Comment: I've updated my answer to address this.